# Continuous Integration and Delivery in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, continuous-deployment, autoscaling

I am figuring out the best approach to perform the following steps in an automated way:

A code is committed in GITLabs then a Trigger implemented in AWS gets notified and A script in AWS instance pulls the new code from GITLabs and deploys

I want this to be implemented to the instances launched through an auto-scaling group.

I know I can make use of the user-data commands, but that would only make sure the fresh data is pulled while the instance is launched. But once an instance is launched, then if code check-in happens, the server won't get pushed with the new code.